# Why isn't my average working properly? C++

Tags: c++, average

it seems that I'm stuck at c++ yet again. woohoo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int amount = 0;
    int inputNumber = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int lowest;
    int highest;
    double averages;

    cout << "Welcome to simple calculator. Where you can use for average, highest amd lowest value.";
    cout << "Please input all the number you plan to use to calculate. ";
    cout << "Finish your input by enter any letter and then press on enter. " << endl;

    while(cin >> inputNumber)
    {
        

        if (inputNumber < lowest) {

            int (lowest = inputNumber);

        }

        else if(inputNumber > highest){

            int (highest = inputNumber);
            
        }
        
        amount = amount += inputNumber;
        n++;
    }

    double averages = amount / n;

    cout << "Your lowest value is: " << lowest << endl;
    cout << "Your highest value is: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "Your average value is: " << averages << endl;
    cout << "Amount is " << amount << endl;
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

but when I put in numbers it doesn't work properly. like

```
3
5
d
Your lowest value is: 3
Your Highest value is: 5
Your average value is: 4
2
```

```
-2
-3
a
Your lowest value is: -3
Your Highest value is: 0
Your average value is: -2
2
```

Idk why it do this and I'm still new to C++, I also have to code it in Linux and use G++

Thanks in advance if you could help me out.

Comment: you need to learn to debug your own programs. Debugging will save you tons of hours of just staring at your code not knowing what is wrong.

Comment: why don't you save this in a double vector?

Comment: `lowest` and `highest` are not initialized

Comment: `lowest` and `highest` will be assigned 0. When your inputs are less than 0, 0 will be larger than those negative values. That's why it keeps 0 as `highest`

Comment: `int (lowest = inputNumber);` why the int ()?

Comment: NB: The posted 'duplicate' answer doesn't answer the question as edited. I've voted for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

try `average = double(amount)/double(n);`
Because average is double and n and amount

Comment: somehow the decimal not working. it just spit out 2 and not 2.5 when I put 2+3

Comment: Not a fan of recommending a C-style cast.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your code:

1. variable averages is defined twice.

Since for calculating amount you are doing int/int. which in result will yield int.
Thus your answer for -3 2 d will come wrong.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int amount = 0;
    int inputNumber = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int lowest=INT_MAX;
    int highest=INT_MIN;

    cout << "Welcome to simple calculator. Where you can use for average, highest amd lowest value.";
    cout << "Please input all the number you plan to use to calculate. ";
    cout << "Finish your input by enter any letter and then press on enter. " << endl;

    while(cin >> inputNumber)
    {


        if (inputNumber < lowest) {

            int (lowest = inputNumber);

        }

        else if(inputNumber > highest){

            int (highest = inputNumber);

        }

        amount += inputNumber;
        n++;
    }

    double averages = (double)amount / n;

    cout << "Your lowest value is: " << lowest << endl;
    cout << "Your highest value is: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "Your average value is: " << averages << endl;
    cout << "Amount is " << amount << endl;
    cout << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This above code is correct code

Comment: Still not fully working.
when I put 2 + 3
I got 
Your lowest value is: 2
Your Highest value is: 0
Your average value is: 2
n = 2

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. When I ran the above program using ``` 2 3 d ``` as input. I am getting 2.5 as output. It is working fine for me